# Why Qt is making developers to include their dlls for every application?

Tags: windows, qt, deployment

I noticed that deployed on windows Qt applications are always including the dlls they needed.
Why did they made it that way?
Why can't they do it like on linux? - You install needed Qt version to system, and then every application that need it - can use it, e.g. only one instance of libraries(excluding different versions like qt4/qt5).

Wouldn't it be better to make it like Java/.Net, e.g. you install Java/.Net then you run/develop applications using only one instance of libraries(dlls).

I find it kinda "unconservating": I have 7 applications that use Qt5, and all of them have `Qt5Core.dll`, `Qt5GUI.dll`, etc. and every of them takes some space. Feels like I have 7 packs of Qt5 libraries... x_x

While on linux these same applications use only "one" Qt library.

Comment: The philosophy on Windows is more to be independent from problems of other programs. Centralization has the problem that a bug tears down every program which uses that DLL. So rather use a few bytes more on huge harddisks.

Comment: @falkb Isn't Qt a framework? Then why it can't be installed and later used as Java/.Net(when its not installed) for example? 

`the problem that a bug tears down every program which uses that DLL`: well if there is problem with framework then how does it work fine on linux? `The philosophy on Windows is more to be independent from problems of other programs` But it is a framework, why it should be included every time...? If there is problem with the framework it is the problem with the framework, not the application itself.

Comment: You are lucky. What if you have applications built against different versions of Qt (4.x, 3.x, 5.x)? How would you solve it with your single Qt installation for all applications?

Comment: Deployment to the user’s computer is not controlled by the Qt Company, but by you, the provider of the software, so if you have a bunch of applications, there’s nothing preventing you from installing shared components like the Qt DLLs. I’d say more often than not, developers want to control all aspects of deployment, like the exact Qt version used (because it was tested), and not have some upgrade “injected” that might cause regressions.

Comment: @BladeMight: Imagine a company which invested months in testing their version. They don't want to risk an unstable release because someone changed an externally located Qt.dll, they don't want to hand over control.

Comment: @falkb, I would say, it's not a Windows philosophy only. What about macOS with its application bundles?

Comment: @BladeMight: You always have the choice to install your Qt to e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\BladeMight and let your 7 applications share that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I noticed that deployed on windows Qt applications are always including the dlls they needed.

This is called "local deployment".

> Why did they made it that way?

I can think of a few reasons.

1. To avoid [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).
2. It is sanctioned by Microsoft. They wrote, *"You can use this deployment method to enable installation by users who don't have administrator rights, or for applications that can be run from a network share."* (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/choosing-a-deployment-method?view=vs-2019)

> You install needed Qt version to system, and then every application that need it - can use it, e.g. only one instance of libraries(excluding different versions like qt4/qt5)

Qt is a C++ library. C++ DLLs can differ by more than just a major version number. The DLLs could be built with MinGW, or they could be built with MSVC; They could be 32-bit, or they could be 64-bit. The different variants are incompatible with each other.

Example: if you force a PC to have one global copy of Qt 5.14.1 MSVC 32-bit and put that in your PATH, then:

- Other Qt apps on that PC that are built with MinGW cannot run.
- Other Qt apps on that PC that are 64-bit cannot run.
- Apps that must use Qt 5.13 might be broken. (For example, if a critical bug exists in Qt 5.14)

> Why can't they do it like on linux? .... on linux these same applications use only "one" Qt library.

I listed a few disadvantages of this approach above. In addition, the version of Qt in Linux distros are usually a few versions behind so applications in the distro repository cannot make use the latest features, bugfixes, or improvements.

That's part of the reason why systems like [AppImage and Snapcraft](https://www.ostechnix.com/linux-package-managers-compared-appimage-vs-snap-vs-flatpak/) were invented.  Sometimes, Linux users also want an app to contain a copy of its libraries, instead of having a single global copy of the libraries.

Comment: Good answer - another point I'd add is that it enables developers to only have to distribute a subset of binaries. A full Qt distribution is several hundred megabytes. A typical application may only need a small subset of that functionality.

Comment: Well this makes sence, thank you for your answer @JKSH